# How to add typing delay in botkit conversations with facebook adapter

Tags: node.js, facebook-messenger-bot, botkit, botkit-4, botkit-middleware

We are building a facebook messenger bot with Botkit version 4.

We have tried different ways to add typing delay with the messages but none of them is working properly.

<s>As we are using the conversations we are unable to use this format in middleware</s>

```
bot.reply(message, { type: "typing" });
```

So we are using something like the following:

**Solution 1**

```
controller.middleware.send.use(async function (bot, message, next) {
    if (bot._config && bot._config.activity && bot._config.activity.conversation && bot._config.activity.conversation.id) {
        await typingIndicator(bot,bot._config.activity.conversation.id)
        setTimeout(async () => { next(); }, 2000);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});

async function typingIndicator(bot, id) {
    await bot.api.callAPI('/me/messages', 'post', {
        recipient: { id: id }, sender_action: 'typing_on'
    })
}
```

But this implementation is not working as expected.

I have around 200 - 300 threads so I tried adding the delay using [**convo.before()**](https://botkit.ai/docs/v4/reference/core.html#before)
But even this is breaking in between

**Solution 2**

```
let dialog = new BotkitConversation('dialog', controller);

dialog.addMessage({text: 'Message 1', action: 'thread_2'}, 'thread_1');
dialog.addMessage({text: 'Message 2', action: 'thread_3'}, 'thread_2');
dialog.addMessage({text: 'Message 3', action: 'thread_4'}, 'thread_3');
dialog.addMessage({text: 'Message 4'}, 'thread_4');

for (let key in dialog.script) {
    dialog.before(`${key}`, async (convo, bot) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
        });
    });
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this now:

```
async function middlewareTest(bot, message, next) {
  if(message.text.length > 0){
    let time = message.text.length * 30;
    await setTimeout(async ()=> {await next();}, time);
  } else {
    await next();
  } 
}

controller.middleware.send.use(middlewareTest);
```

I check if the messages text that is going to be sent has more than 0 characters. If thats the case I do a timeout.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, did you check if it's working properly when multiple users are talking

Comment: Working in 4+, yes.
Not tested with multiple users.

Comment: Just checked but unfortunately, this is not working properly when 2 users are chatting simultaneously